# ¿Qué evento ocurre cuando dejo presionado pero el cursor está fuera del elemento en Android?

Tags: android, material-design

Necesito saber si existe desde mi clase java, algun evento que me determine cuando sigo haciendo click en un elemento (para mi caso sería un botón) pero mi cursor está fuera de este elemento. Ahora explico mi problema para que sepan a donde quiero llegar:

Lo que estoy buscando es que cuando el usuario presione sobre esté botón, se le agregue un *Padding* y cambie su color de fondo; pero si al seguir presionando, mueve su cursor o dedo a otro lado de la vista, que este botón vuelva a tener sus propiedades originales.

Una de las cosas que pensé para resolver el problema del Padding era hacer uso del evento *setOnTouchListener* y agregar una condición como

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
// button.setPadding(0, 55, 0, 0);
}
```

Pero esto se cumple solo cuando presiono y no tiene en cuenta si arrastro a otro lado el cursor.

Y para el caso del color de fondo, lo que intente fue hacerlo desde un *.xml* y determinar si este elemento está siendo presionado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_press" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_nopress" />
</selector>
```

Esto me funciona. El botón cambia sus propiedades de fondo en base a si se está presionando o no, pero sigo teniendo el problema del *Padding*. Tambien intente agregar un etiqueta `<padding android:top="30dp"/>` en mi *@drawable/button_press* pero el padding se establece sin ni siquiera que el botón esté presionado (cosa que no entendí)

En conclusión, si pudiera hacer que solo el *Padding* vuelva a su posición original (al presionar y moverse a otro lado de la vista), estaría resolviendo el problema.

Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Comment: Quieres decir que cuando arrastres el dedo fuera de la vista y lo quites, determine que esta fuera de la vista.

Comment: Claro pero "sin quitarlo", es decir que se estaría ejecutando el evento `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. De esta manera voy a poder saber cuando se esté presionando pero no en el botón (donde inicialmente había empezado). Te paso la publicacion en ingles donde muestro las imagenes del efecto que quiero obtener: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310859/how-set-padding-when-an-button-is-touched-but-the-pointer-is-out-of-my-button

Comment: Recuerda que si la respuesta era lo que estabas buscando, cómo has indicado, debes otorgar los +50 de recompensa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente approach usando MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.  En el momento de hacer el ACTION_DOWN se crea un rectángulo para conocer las medidas de tu vista.  AL desplazarte por la pantalla, se captura el evento de moviento en ACTION_MOVE y ahí se compara la posición actual está dentro de los límites definidos.

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
            // User moved outside bounds
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando. Funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias!!!!